# Two way preposition issue: an

Tags: preposition

Obviously we know the two way prepositions.

> Es liegt auf dem Tisch - It is on the table
>
> Es wird auf den Tisch hingelegt - It is being placed on the table

Dative for something that is already in the place of destination.
Accusative for something that is traversing towards place of destination.

However for *an* there seems to be an issue:

> Er hat etw an der Wand befestigt
>
> Er klebt das am Tisch fest

This does not comply with the two way prepositional rule, it is not already sticking to the table it is in the process of being stuck on yet it takes dative. 
Can someone explain why?

Comment: It fits with the two-way rule if you consider *an der Wand* or *am Tisch* as the location where something is happening. Likewise, ‘Er hängt das an **die** Wand’ is also valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you trying to express. *Festkleben* is a bit bad example, let's use *hängen* instead.

> Der Angler hängt den Köder an den Haken.

*The angler pins the bait on the hook.*

> Der Köder hängt am Haken.

*The bait hangs down from the hook.*

---

So, why not with *festkleben*. Because it has *fest* == *tight/sticky* in it so people frown from involving a movement into the sentence. This can be puzzling to English speakers, because there is a verb *to stick* for this. Okay, German has **befestigen**, but that one is a bit highbrow and says nothing about how to do that (as English *to stick*).

> Er klebt den Fuß an den Tisch.

*He glues the leg to the table.*

> Er klebt den Fuß am Tisch **fest**.
>
> Er be**fest**igt den Fuß am Tisch.

*He sticks the leg to the table.*